# Best Practice on Where to Perform Iteration

Tags: java, language-agnostic

I've come across the following code at work and it raised a question in my mind.

```
\\Option 1
public class MyObjectRegistry 
{
    private MyObjectMapper mapper = new MyObjectMapper();
    public void StoreMyObjects (List<MyObject> myObjectList) 
    {
        mapper.StoreMyObjects(myObjectList); 
    }
}

public class MyObjectMapper
{
    public void StoreMyObjects(List<MyObject> myObjectList)
    {
        for (MyObject myObj : myObjectList)
        {
            //Store Object In Database
        }
    }
}
```

vs

```
\\Option 2
public class MyObjectRegistry 
{
    private MyObjectMapper mapper = new MyObjectMapper();
    public void StoreMyObjects (List<MyObject> myObjectList) 
    {
        for (MyObject myObj : myObjectList)
        {
            mapper.StoreMyObject(myObj); 
        }
    }
}

public class MyObjectMapper
{
    public void StoreMyObject(MyObject myObject)
    {
            //Store Object In Database
    }
}
```

Option 1 is currently what is in the code base.  My question is: Is one of these approaches better than the other?  Are there any conventions or best practices regarding a situation like this regarding where the iteration should take place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one should definitely be preferred. The second example keeps calling an external method which is much more resource demanding than the first due to the abstraction involved. The lower level you can keep your iterations the better.

Answer (score 0):

The way it is now, with a List in the method signature, should definitely be preferred because the performance of database insertion is dramatically better with insert batching. With the code designed as in the second example, batching would be a great pain to implement, which means it probably *wouldn't* be implemented.